# How do you make elimination races in the GTA Online Content Creator?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online, grand-theft-auto-content-creator

I saw a YouTuber playing an elimination race and in the Content Creator, I noticed that I couldn't create my own. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I remember it's destroy last place

Comment: I hope I was right was I right?

Comment: You should add a bit more details on _how_ you destry the last place, so this answer can help those who might be wondering the same thing.